# using pandas in python to append csv files into one

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have n files in a directory that I need to combine into one. They have the same amount of columns, for example, the contents of `test1.csv` are:

```
test1,test1,test1  
test1,test1,test1  
test1,test1,test1
```

Similarly, the contents of `test2.csv` are:

```
test2,test2,test2  
test2,test2,test2  
test2,test2,test2
```

I want final.csv to look like this:

```
test1,test1,test1  
test1,test1,test1  
test1,test1,test1  
test2,test2,test2  
test2,test2,test2  
test2,test2,test2
```

But instead it comes out like this:

```
test file 1,test file 1.1,test file 1.2,test file 2,test file 2.1,test file 2.2  
,,,test file 2,test file 2,test file 2  
,,,test file 2,test file 2,test file 2  
test file 1,test file 1,test file 1,,,  
test file 1,test file 1,test file 1,,,
```

Can someone help me figure out what is going on here? I have pasted my code below:

```
import csv
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

all_data = pd.DataFrame() #initializes DF which will hold aggregated csv files

for f in glob.glob("*.csv"): #for all csv files in pwd
    df = pd.read_csv(f) #create dataframe for reading current csv
    all_data = all_data.append(df) #appends current csv to final DF

all_data.to_csv("final.csv", index=None)
```

Comment: Why are you using pandas just to create a single csv ?

Comment: I'm a noob and I thought this was the best way to do it. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are more problems:

1. I removed `import csv` and `import numpy as np`, because in this demo they are not used (but maybe they in missing, lines so they can be imported)
2. I created list of all dataframes `dfs`, where dataframes are appended by `dfs.append(df)`. Then I used function `concat` for joining this list to final dataframe.
3. In function [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) I added parameter `header=None`, because the main problem was that `read_csv` reads first row as `header`.
4. In function `to_csv` I added parameter `header=None` for omitting header.
5. I added folder `test` to final destination file, because if use function `glob.glob("*.csv")` you should read output file as input file.

Solution:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

all_data = pd.DataFrame() #initializes DF which will hold aggregated csv files

#list of all df
dfs = []
for f in glob.glob("*.csv"): #for all csv files in pwd
    #add parameters to read_csv
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None) #create dataframe for reading current csv
    #print df
    dfs.append(df) #appends current csv to final DF
all_data = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print all_data
#       0      1      2
#0  test1  test1  test1
#1  test1  test1  test1
#2  test1  test1  test1
#3  test2  test2  test2
#4  test2  test2  test2
#5  test2  test2  test2
all_data.to_csv("test/final.csv", index=None, header=None)
```

Next solution is similar.
I add parameter `header=None` to `read_csv` and `to_csv` and add parameter `ignore_index=True` to `append`.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

all_data = pd.DataFrame() #initializes DF which will hold aggregated csv files

for f in glob.glob("*.csv"): #for all csv files in pwd
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None) #create dataframe for reading current csv
    all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True) #appends current csv to final DF
print all_data
#       0      1      2
#0  test1  test1  test1
#1  test1  test1  test1
#2  test1  test1  test1
#3  test2  test2  test2
#4  test2  test2  test2
#5  test2  test2  test2

all_data.to_csv("test/final.csv", index=None, header=None)
```

Comment: I think `pandas` is very good library for data processing. So you can try it. And if you are new in Stackoverflow, you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

You can `concat`. Let `df1` be your first dataframe and `df2` the second, you can:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)
```

The `ignore_index` is optional, you can set it to `True` if you don't mind the original indexes of the single dataframes.

Comment: This will work, if you pass "axis=0" as a parameter.

Comment: @hahdawg thanks for pointing it out. Actually 0 is the default value for `axis` in `concat`.

Comment: @JackBauer you're welcome. Please consider to accept one of the two answers received to help other users.

Comment: I have limited experience with this stuff so it will take me some time to go through it all but I definitely will.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` is not a tool to use when all you want is to create a single csv file, you can simply write each csv to a new file as you go:

```
import glob

with open("out.csv","w") as out:
    for fle in glob.glob("*.csv"):
        with open(fle) as f:
             out.writelines(f)
```

Or with the csv lib if you prefer:

```
import glob
import csv

with open("out.csv", "w") as out:
    wr = csv.writer(out)
    for fle in glob.glob("*.csv"):
        with open(fle) as f:
            wr.writerows(csv.reader(f))
```

Creating a large dataframe just to eventually write to disk makes no real sense, furthermore if you had a lot of large files it may not even be possible.

Comment: No worries, pandas is a great tool if you actually want to do some computation on the data, it is not the tool to use to concat a few files into one